# Remover todas linhas que comecem com algum caractere específico

Tags: php

Olá,

Tenho um projeto que usa `file_get_contents();` numa página externa e gostaria de saber como eu posso remover por exemplo, todas as linhas que comecem com `//`.

A página externa contém comentários em JavaScript's e não encontrei nada que possa remover apenas comentários dentro da tag.

Exemplo de código da página externa;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
[...]
// Alerta
alert('Olá!');
[...]
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Código que tentei usar para remover os comentários;

```
$html = explode(PHP_EOL, file_get_contents('https://example.com/'));
foreach($html as $linha) {
    if(substr($linha, 0, 2) !== '//' && mb_substr($linha, 0, 2) !== '//') {
        $linhas[] = trim($linha);
    }
}
$html = implode(PHP_EOL, $linhas);
echo $html;
```

Quando executei o script pelo navegador para observar se removeu o comentário ou não, infelizmente ainda obtive o comentário.

Estou usando o XAMPP na versão `5.6.35`.

Comment: Seria importante explicar o "não obtive exito" melhor, e como testou a saída. Além disso, não faz muito sentido usar substr E mb_substr no teste, principalmente pelo fato de os caracteres não serem multibyte. Creio ainda que seria bom fazer um `trim` na string, caso queira eliminar comentários que não estejam na primeira posição

Comment: Usei `substr` junto com `mb_substr` só para ter a certeza que não haveria erro, mas não saiu como pensei haha.

Comment: Tente dar um print_r em cada linha (sem o teste do '//') para ter certeza que o texto está vindo como você imagina, e o explode estar acontecendo no lugar certo.

Comment: Não creio que PHP_EOL seja o melhor critério no explode, pois pode ser CRLF na sua plataforma, mas só CR ou LF na origem. Eu provavelmente preferiria `explode( chr(10), file_get_contents ....`, ou `explode( "\n", file_get....`

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar expressões regulares para Resolver esse problema. No meu padrão de regex estou procurando por linhas que comece por "/" seguida de outra /. Por fim eu nego as linhas que casem com esse padrão.

padrão : "/^///"

```
<?php 

 $html = explode(PHP_EOL, file_get_contents('./teste.html'));
   foreach($html as $linha) {
    if(!preg_match("/^\/\//", $linha)) {
     $linhas[] = trim($linha);
    }
  }
  $html = implode(PHP_EOL, $linhas);
  echo $html;
?>
```

Arquivo HTML exemplo.

```
LINHA 1 <br>
LINHA 2 <br>
LINHA 3 <br>
//NAO LEIA <br>
LINHA 4 <br>
```

Saída:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]